# Error in Reading MFC file in c# using Memorymappedfile

Tags: c#, mfc, memory-mapped-files

Iam reading file created in mfc application using CFile in c# using memorymappedfile.
But it shows below error while executing.

*the input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 45-53-49-4D-20-00-31-30-30-00-00-42-4C-43-30-31-00 ...*

CFile code in MFC:

```
char TempCharData[25];
TempInfo = Temp->GetTagName();          //Tag Name
memset(TempCharData,0,25);
strncpy(TempCharData,(const char *)TempInfo,TempInfo.GetLength());
ofTag.Write(TempCharData,(int)TagNameLength);
TempInfo = Temp->GetDescription();      // Description
memset(TempCharData,0,25);
strncpy(TempCharData,(const char *)TempInfo,TempInfo.GetLength());
ofTag.Write(TempCharData,24);
```

Im reading this file in c# as below:

```
 MemoryMappedFile mmf1 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("C:\\BL001\\YCS\\Tag.YCS", FileMode.Open);
 MemoryMappedViewAccessor mmfReader = mmf1.CreateViewAccessor();
 byte[] buffer = new byte[mmfReader.Capacity];
 mmfReader.ReadArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();    
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);      
 return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);   //Shows error here
```

Comment: This can never work, BinaryFormatter.Deserialize() can only ever deserialize an object that was written by its Serialize() method.  Not the case here of course, MFC knows beans about BinaryFormatter.  You'll need to use BinaryReader.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in reading the file but in deserialization. The `BinaryFormatter` can't determine what is stored in the file. If you want to get two strings from the file then you must write your own `TextReader` or use existing classes (`BinaryReader` or `StreamReader`) and modify the C++ file. I will write only about using `BinaryReader` because it's the easiest way.

BinaryReader can read strings if they are written in the following format:

> [length][chars]

- length - 7 bit encoded length in bytes of a follolowing string.
- chars - string's charactes

**C++ file:**

```
void Write7BitEncodedInt(CFile& file, int strLen)
{
    char lenPart;

    while (strLen >= 128)
    {
        lenPart = (char)(strLen | 128);
        file.Write(&lenPart, 1);
        strLen >>= 7;
    }

    lenPart = (char)strLen;
    file.Write(&lenPart, 1);
}

// Use this function to write strings to the file
void WriteString(CFile& file, CString& str)
{
    const char* chars = str;
    int strLen = str.GetLength();

    Write7BitEncodedInt(file, strLen);
    file.Write(chars, strLen);
}
```

**C# file:**

```
var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("C:\\BL001\\YCS\\Tag.YCS", FileMode.Open);
var mmfReader = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
var buffer = new byte[mmfReader.Capacity];

mmfReader.ReadArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    var reader = new BinaryReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII);

    var tag = reader.ReadString();
    var description = reader.ReadString();
}
```